Uncaught DivisionbyZeroError: Wp_reschedule_event
I've really been struggling with my wordpress running smoothly and have been constantly dealing with a variety of issues. One thing that i continue to experience is Cron scheduled tasks will end up past due, then that will start to prevent analytics and other things to stop working and i believe just cause my site to get sluggish overall possibly?
I recently set my server to run my cron and take over to see if that fixes things. Something interesting was after i set it to "run now" it said it completed but with an error in 3 seconds. This was the error:

Task "httpdocs/wp-cron.php" completed with error in 3 seconds, output:
Fatal error: Uncaught DivisionByZeroError: Modulo by zero in
/var/www/vhosts/newstatebranding.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/cron.php:436
Stack trace:
#0 /var/www/vhosts/newstatebranding.com/httpdocs/wp-cron.php(129): wp_reschedule_event()
#1 {main} thrown in /var/www/vhosts/newstatebranding.com/httpdocs/wp-includes/cron.php on
line 436

This is whats on line 436:
    $timestamp = $now + ( $interval - ( ( $now - $timestamp ) % $interval ) );
}

Currently i have cron scheduled for every 10minutes via plesk. I'm not too sure if it is working though as when i manually run it that shows up but then also when i check my Wordpress scheduled tasks - i always have "past due" tasks.
Any idea on what this means exactly, and better yet - how to fix all of this?
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

This looks like $interval is 0, and so the ( $now - $timestamp ) % $interval is attempting to divide by zero. Please edit your question to include how you're scheduling your cron tasks, if you can; that'll give us a better chance at diagnosing the problem.

Thanks Pat. I updated it with that info.
